# Change Schema of dataframe in pySpark

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I have to change the schema of the dataframe by calling the schema from JSON file.

```
df1.show()
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|c  |2  |
+---+---+
printSchema:
  a: string (nullable - true)
  b: long (nullable - true)
```

New schema in json file is as follows:

```
{ "schema": ["a StringType() False", "b IntegerType() False"] }
```

Now, I'm calling the json file and passing the new schema as follows:

```
with open('/path/app.json') as f:
   config = json.load(f)

new_schema = [StructField(e.split(' ')[0], e.split(' ')[1], e.split(' ')[2]) for e in config]
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(df1.rdd, StructType(new_schema))
```

I'm getting error like:

```
Failed to convert JSON string \'{"metadata": {}, "name": "a", "nullable": "false" .... to a field.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors with your code,

first, with this statement -

```
new_schema = [StructField(e.split(' ')[0], e.split(' ')[1], e.split(' ')[2]) for e in config]
```

here, you should be accessing the value part of json atribute `schema` like -

```
new_schema = [StructField(e.split(' ')[0], eval(e.split(' ')[1]), 
              e.split(' ')[2]) for e in config["schema"]]
```

Second, the type inside StructField should be evaluated as code otherwise, you are just created a structfield with (string,string,string) instead of `(name, dataType, nullable)`

to fix this, use `eval()` on `e.split(' ')[1]` function and convert  `e.split(' ')[1]` to boolean -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
new_schema = [StructField(e.split(' ')[0], 
eval(e.split(' ')[1]), 
bool(e.split(' ')[2])) for e in config["schema"]]
```

Comment: Thank you..it got worked. but `bool(e.split(' ')[2]` is giving me output as true...even though the value in JSON file is False.

Comment: You can leave out bool() conversion and see if that works